# iPhone - How do I make viewControllers landscape?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, landscape

I have a uiNavigationController and two viewControllers. The problem I am having is the views are being generated in portrait size even though I want them in landscape!

Here is what I am doing:

1) Creating an instance of view1 and adding it to the uiNavigationControllers stack. This is performed inside the applications delegate didFinishLoadingWithOptions(...) method.

2) view1 has a button that when clicked creates an instance of view2 and pushes it onto the uiNavigationControllers stack.

This appears to work fine apart from the fact the views are being created in portrait format. I was going to manually force landscape by using transform methods once I create their instance but this feels really hacky.

I did speculate that this has something to do with the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" method, but this is set for landscape in all viewControllers.

I am royally confused.

Question 1) How on earth do I solve this, is the 'hacky transform' approach the only way?

Question 2) Is this the correct way to be using a navigationController - I am new to iPhone programming. All I want are two landscape views that I can click between and this seems to do this aside from the landscape bit ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this problem.

The navigation controller DOES inherit the shouldAuthororateToInterfaceOrierntation method for each of the views inside its stack, I however made a mistake :)

After adding the navController to the main window I had not deleted the part where by default it adds the a rootController view to the main window. There was some kind of conflict which stopped my navigation controller working as expecting - removing that line fixed everything.